# Publication (web): Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to publish a web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I have a Visual Studio 2010 web application which I was able to build, debug and publish fine until yesterday.

I use Telerik Ajax Controls and I user Ajax Control Toolkit here.

Things used to work like a charm.

For another project I wanted MVC so I tried installing the VS 2010 SP 1 and as it broke my IntelliSence in SQL Management Studio (2008 R2) I installed the SP 1 for SQL Server.

these are the only changes I did to my laptop and now I cant publish any website or application (things that i previously published as well) as it gives me "Publication (web): Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

1. I've tried replacing all the DLLs
2. removed the VS 2010 SP 1 and VS 2010 and re-installed both
3. cleared the asp.net temp folders
4. updated my Telerik DLLs

Nothing seem to work. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to build the project?

Comment: have you try to create new asp.net project and publish?

Comment: try to manually delete object/bin folders then build and publish.

Comment: @Nilesh Yes I can build and run the project.

Comment: @Damith I tried creating a new web application and publish it, only the default.aspx and about.aspx page were there. Still i couldn't publish it.

Comment: try to clear vs cache

Comment: Take a look here to clean up VS: http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/11/08/clean-up-after-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

after so many hours of browsing through the internet and trying out every possible suggestion, i decided to format my machine and see if i could publish web applications afterwards. even that didn't work.
I was running out of options when **i decided to upgrade my VS 2010 to VS 2013. which solved the problem entirely.**